# Android - How efficient is it to use handler thread for long delay?

Tags: android, handler, delayed-execution

So...I have this handler thread to do something after some time has passed. This time could be a few seconds or could be minutes or hours. The question is:

How efficient is it to use a handler.postDelayed thread for a delay that could be that long in terms of memory and cpu usage etc.. (I can make sure it won't be killed by the system because so that is not an issue )

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
             .
             .
             .
             .
    }
},delay});
```

Comment: I would prefer using `AlarmManager` if delay is more than a minute or something, yet I dont know the right answer.

Comment: i know how to user AlarmManager but with the current setup of my code it's much more convinient for me to use handler. So I wonder how big the difference is if any resources-wise.